Mesibo Sdk flutter
How can I remove screen share button on calls for mesibo flutter sdk? For now, we don't need that for our app
should I create native files or can do that using flutter recources? i have basic configurations like this (from sample app)
void initLoginMesibo(String token) async {
    mesibo
      ..setAccessToken(token)
      ..setListener(this)
      ..start();

    await mesiboUi.getUiDefaults().then((MesiboUIOptions options) {
      options
        ..enableBackButton = true
        ..toolbarColor = 0xff00868b;
      mesiboUi.setUiDefaults(options);
    });

    final MesiboUIButtons buttons = MesiboUIButtons();
    buttons.message = false;
    buttons.audioCall = true;
    buttons.videoCall = true;
    buttons.groupAudioCall = true;
    buttons.groupVideoCall = true;
    buttons.endToEndEncryptionInfo = true;
    mesiboUi.setupBasicCustomization(buttons, null);
  }


Can you share a screenshot and point out which button you are referring to?

Thanks. Currently, you need to add native code in your Flutter app, get default call properties, and then set showScreenSharing to false. https://docs.mesibo.com/api/calls/ However, I can create an internal ticket to add this in the Flutter configuration.

that will be great option to add opportunity to customise call screens from flutter side

We have released 2.5.3 with options to configure the conferencing/group call UI. Please update and use the code below which is self-explanatory and similar to the code that you have used for one-to-one calls earlier.
MesiboGroupCallUiProperties gcp = MesiboGroupCallUiProperties();

// show or hide screen sharing 
gcp.screenSharingButton = false;

// customize participant joined and left notification message 
gcp.joinMessage = "has graced us with their presence!";
gcp.leftMessage = "had better things to do, bye bye";

// show or hide participant controls 
gcp.participantControls = true; 

_mesiboUi.setGroupCallUiDefaults(gcp);

Hope that helps. Note that, the X button is to end the participant call and not to end the entire group call. You can still press the red hangup button to end the call.

Please update mesibo flutter SDK to 2.3.0 and use the following code:
MesiboCallUiProperties cp = MesiboCallUiProperties();
cp.showScreenSharing = false;
mesiboUi.setCallUiDefaults(cp);

Let us know if there are any issues.

thank you, that works for realtime calls (for version 2.5.2), when we create group call there still is an option to share screen, so could you add option to disable that for group calls please ? And there is one more problem with buttons on group call screen, when we press for example button to expand our colleague view and then press X-button we dont have opportunity to end call, should i create another ticket for that ?

We will let you once we implement it, but we do not have a specific timeline.
Please note that our UI support is limited. The entire UI is open-source, allowing you to modify it according to your preferences. While we're happy to assist with minor changes, we cannot release updates for every small UI request. Hence, we kindly request that you state all your related requirements upfront. For example, the group call button wasn't mentioned in your original request.  In the meantime, please let us know if you need any additional changes.

thank you for all  your help and support, should i write all proposed changes here or maybe send you email? What way will be better for you ?

Please send us an email. It will be easier for us to keep track of it. Thanks
